# Handling Failure in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

This is my simple HTTP client for some api:

> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> import settings
> from twisted.internet import reactor
> from twisted.web.client import Agent
> from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
>
> params = {
>     'url': 'http://api.vk.com/api.php',
>     'id':260,
>     }
>
>
> def params_for_get():
>     return '&'.join(["%s=%s" % (key,val) for key, val in params.items()])
>
>
> agent = Agent(reactor)
> d = agent.request(
>     'GET',
>     "%s?%s" % (settings.APPLICATION_URL, params_for_get()),
>     Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example'],
>              'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']}),
>     '')
>
> def cbResponse(*args, **kwargs):
>     print args, kwargs
>     print 'Response received'
>
>
> def cbShutdown(ignored):
>     reactor.stop()
>
> def cbError(failure):
>     print type(failure.value), failure # catch error here
>
>
> d.addCallbacks(cbResponse, cbError)
> d.addBoth(cbShutdown)
>
>
> reactor.run()
> ```

When I start program, I catch error:

```
<class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'> [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>>]
]
```

But I don't know, where this error happened.
How I can know it?
I tried to display traceback for

```
<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>>
```

but I could not get.

Comment: You may want to try "getErrorMessage()" on the failure instance to see if it provides a bit more information.

Comment: The fact that you get such a crummy error message here is a bug in Twisted.  See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5310

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That Failure instance is wrapping another Failure instance, and isn't printing much information about the one inside. This awkwardness is Twisted's fault; the `twisted.web._newclient._WrapperException` class stores a `reasons` attribute, but doesn't seem to care about printing information about those reasons in its `__str__` method.

You could see the rest of your problem if you add another line to your cbError() function:

```
failure.value.reasons[0].printTraceback()
```

I can reproduce the error here, and with the extra information it's apparent that your fourth parameter to `Agent.request()` is supposed to be an `IBodyProducer` provider, but you're passing an empty string instead. Try removing that last parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by the-paul above is correct.  I wanted to provide this short function that I found useful in flattening out the Failures, but I couldn't put it in a comment:

```
def unwrap_failures(err):
    """
    Takes nested failures and flattens the nodes into a list.
    The branches are discarded.
    """
    errs = []
    check_unwrap = [err]
    while len(check_unwrap) > 0:
        err = check_unwrap.pop()
        if hasattr(err.value, 'reasons'):
            errs.extend(err.value.reasons)
            check_unwrap.extend(err.value.reasons)
        else:
            errs.append(err)
    return errs
```